# How to make a small logo on mobile look sharp?

Tags: graphics, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, graphical-logo

My website logo has size of 300x50 px. It looks fine on desktop. But when I open my site on mobile, it gets smaller and looks blur like there are pixels around its edge.

How can I make it looks sharp even in very small size?

Comment: What mobile device are you using? If it's a display with a x2-scale, you will have to use a bigger size of you logo because your device is scaling the image up to the preferred size and then it doesn't look very sharp.

Comment: Use a vector image format?

Comment: I have read some and they suggest to user Tracing function on AI or photoshop. I tried and it didn't work. Not sure im doing it correct or not. (I never used neither AI nor photoshop before :( )

Answer (score 2):

Your blurred image issue probably comes from using a non-retina or HiDPI image on a retina/HiDPI device. This means if you want to a 300x50px image to look sharp on a retina device you either need to use a vector based image (e.g. SVG) or a double(2x - e.g. iPhone6 - 600x100px) or triple sized image(3x - e.g. iPhone 6 Plus - 900x150px)

Use `srcset`. Srcset allows you to add multiple images to one img element allowing browsers that support it to pick the correct image for the device. As browsers that don't support `srcset` just fall back to `src`, there is no risk.

```
<img src="myNormalImgForOldBrowsers.jpg" srcset="highResImg.jpg 2x, ultraHighResImg.jpg 3x" alt=" " />
```

In this example I have used jpgs, but the images declared in the srcset example could just as easily be SVG

Answer (score 0):

Use a SVG Rather Then Ico Format. Ico Formats Are Little Bit DIM as compared to SVG